# Automatically find the revisions to merge in Subclipse

Tags: svn, subclipse

Hi I have a Subclipse related question.

In SVN when you merge the trunk to a branch you are working on, you simply use the following command :

```
svn merge http://svn.example.com/rep/trunk
```

And you automatically get all the new changes from the last time you merged the trunk into your branch.

In Subclipse when you select merge you HAVE to select the range of revisions from which to merge changes. Now I know that with proper commenting when you commit changes this is not a big problem but I was wondering if there is an automatic way to simply get all the new changes from the trunk in your branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new subclipse version 1.6 solves this issue...